# Object movement in Unreal using BPs and input touch and ARCore

Tags: mobile, unreal

So I am trying to move an object in Unreal through input touch using ARCore. The problem is that I can't use the simple Screen to world position because it just returns a world position wherever the camera is at the time that you touch. I'm trying to convert the X and Y positions to actual space but, I am having a difficult time with it. Here's what I have so far:

[image: Movement BP]

This works okay, but the movement isn't equal if that makes sense. Obviously it's because I am just pulling the raw coordinates but, I honestly have no idea what I need to do to them in order to get it to move smoothly.

If you're still not following, basically, the closer I get to the left, top edge the slower the object moves and the closer I get to the right bottom edge the faster the movement. This happens because the X and Y coordinates get smaller/larger

What can I do to compensate for this disparity between coordinates?

Is there a way to get like a percentage from the edge of the screen?

Answer (score -2):

Try supplying GetActorRelativeLocation to your "+" Node instead of GetActorLocation.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the GetActorLocation. The problem is because I am using the camera and the level is in essence basically empty there is nothing for me to raycast to determine a coordinate to move the object to and I have to somehow convert screen coordinates to level coordinates but it doesn't work.